# Computational complexity sum of digits square root

Tags: computational-complexity

I know that the sum of digits formula is:

$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$

I am calculating the computation complexity of an algorithm whose while loop is increasing at this factor, hence:

$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}>n$

At the time when the function increases over $n$, the while loop will exit.

Expanding the formula and solving for $k$:

$\frac{k^2+k}{2} > n$

This next line I do not understand, can someone explain how this line is achieved?

$k = O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$

Regards